# No matching function for call to Dice::Dice (class constructor)

Tags: c++

I'm creating a dice game. I'm building the files but get the following error:

> No matching function for call to Dice::Dice

**main.cpp**:

```
#include "Dice.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (){
    Dice d(1,6);
    cout << d.getRoll() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Dice.h**:

```
#ifndef DICE_H
#define DICE_H

class Dice
{
public:
    Dice();
    void getRoll(int m, int n);
};

#endif
```

**Dice.cpp**:

```
#include "Dice.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Dice::Dice()
{}

void Dice::getRoll(int m, int n) {
    srand(time(0));
    (rand() % n)+m;
}
```

Comment: This question should not be voted up!

Answer (score 3):

I see several problems with the code. Here's are my fixes and tips:

Firstly, your construction and method call of `Dice` will not compile:

```
Dice d(1,6);                  // you give arguments to the constructor
cout << d.getRoll() << endl;  // your method call has no arguments
```

But you defined:

```
Dice();                       // constructor takes no arguments
void getRoll(int m, int n);   // method takes arguments
```

Secondly, `srand` only needs to be done once, not every time you call roll – maybe in the main function:

```
srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) );
```

This seeds the generator so that you should get different random numbers every time the program runs. Call it only once, before the first dice roll.

Thirdly, your `getRoll` function returns nothing, meaning you get no value back. And you should name your variables according to what idea they represent in reality or your specification:

```
int Dice::getRoll(int maxEyes) {     // Still no good abstraction
    (rand() % maxEyes) + 1;
}
```

A real dice does not change its `maxEyes` at runtime. Why not try some object orientation instead of a function library class. Think about a real dice object! Here's a dice abstraction to start with:

### main.cpp

```
#include "Dice.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Dice::randomize(); // Try commenting this out and run the program several times, check the result, then comment it back in

    Dice diceWith6Sides(6);
    cout << "The 6 sided dice rolls a " << diceWith6Sides.getRoll() << endl;
    cout << "The 6 sided dice rolls a " << diceWith6Sides.getRoll() << endl;
    cout << "The 6 sided dice rolls a " << diceWith6Sides.getRoll() << endl;

    Dice diceWith20Sides(20);
    cout << "The 20 sided dice rolls a " << diceWith20Sides.getRoll() << endl;
    cout << "The 20 sided dice rolls a " << diceWith20Sides.getRoll() << endl;
    cout << "The 20 sided dice rolls a " << diceWith20Sides.getRoll() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

### Dice.h

```
#ifndef DICE_H
#define DICE_H

class Dice
{
public:
    Dice(int sides);
    int getRoll();

    static void randomize(); // Call only once

private:
    int sides;
};

#endif
```

### Dice.cpp

```
#include "Dice.h"

#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

Dice::Dice(int sides) :
    sides(sides)
{

}

int Dice::getRoll()
{
    return ((rand() % sides) + 1);
}

void Dice::randomize()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
}
```

Hope that is a good starting point. Have a lot of fun!